Multivariable Chain Rule with a scaled Function
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus \{0\}$ and $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$, define the function $g_x : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g_x(\lambda) := f(\lambda x)$. I need to find the derivative $\frac{d}{d\lambda} g_x(\lambda)$.
I know I should apply the chain rule, considering that $\lambda x$ is a product of $\lambda$ and $x$. How do I explicitly calculate this derivative? My result $ \nabla f(\lambda x) \cdot \lambda^2$ seems almost trivial.

Consider $f\!=\!f(w)\,$ where the vector $w$ is defined as
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\derivLR#1#2{\LR{\deriv{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\l{\lambda}
w &= x\l  \qiq \grad w\l = x \\
}$$
Then calculate the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\l$
$$\eqalign{
\deriv{f}{\l}
 = \gradLR{f}{w}\cdot\gradLR{w}{\l}
 \;=\;  \gradLR{f}{w}\cdot x
}$$
